# Cannot resolve symbol 'MobileAds'

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Ok, so I'm working on an android app and I'm trying to put ads in it, but I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'MobileAds'" whenever I try to compile it.

Here's what I have:

```
activity_main.java
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds = null;
private SoundAdapter mAdapter = null;
static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-Removed");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

My XML:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-(removed)</string>
```

Project Gradle

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

App Gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Why am I getting this error message?
any help on this is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Look at your `import` statements in `MainActivity`. Do you have `MobileAds` imported?

Comment: Agh... Lol thanks so much mate!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone having this problem:

Make sure that you have

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
```

in your MainActivity.java

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure you already all the steps of Google AdMob Get started,

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

then go to the Android Studio > Tools > SDK manager > SDK Tools 
and check you have installed 
Google play services & Google Repository[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP7yb.jpg)

if not installed it and then go to the 
Android studio > File > Sync Project with gradle file

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio :

Main activity add ->
[ADD]

```
private final AtomicBoolean isMobileAdsInitializeCalled = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

Refer the page https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#request-ads

Answer (score 0):

If you have import in your activity then be sure to have Maven in Gradle project level:

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```